# How to solve "Property muws_disruptive_ads_minor.POLICY_NAME not found"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, properties, google-play-console

App Status: Rejected
Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to the policy issue(s) listed below. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
Issue found: Property muws_disruptive_ads_minor.TITLE not found
Property muws_disruptive_ads_minor.SHORT_DESCRIPTION not found
Issue details
We found an issue in the following area(s):
•   SPLIT_BUNDLE 1:
About the Property muws_disruptive_ads_minor.POLICY_NAME is not found Policy
Property muws_disruptive_ads_minor.POLICY_DESCRIPTION not found
About the Property muws_disruptive_ads_minor.POLICY_NAME2 not found Policy
Property muws_disruptive_ads_minor.POLICY_DESCRIPTION2 not found
Action required: Submit an updated app for review
Here's what to do to help get your app on Google Play:
1.  Make sure to read the applicable policies or requirements:
o   Property muws_disruptive_ads_minor.POLICY_NAME not found
o   Property muws_disruptive_ads_minor.POLICY_NAME2 not found
2.  Visit Google Play’s Academy for App Success to get contextual learning on this Google Play policy.
3.  Make appropriate changes to your app (if possible), and be sure to address the issue described above. You may also want to check your app's store listing for compliance, if applicable.
4.  Additionally, follow these steps to bring your app into compliance
Property muws_disruptive_ads_minor.NEXT_STEPS not found
5.  Double check that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies.
6.  If you made changes to your app bundle, store listing, or APK, please sign in to your Play Console and submit the update(s).

**What can I do?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the email was not properly formatted. From the text, it is clear, your app was rejected due to [Disruptive Ads](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9857753#disruptive-ads&zippy=).

Are you showing Interstitial ads too frequently or while opening/closing the app?

Make sure Interstitial ads are not blocking the easy navigation and are shown only at appropriate times.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, I think this an error from Google Play that don't fill the message vars but the remanent error is disruptive ads. Check if you are sending clear traffic (no https) to all hosts.